# How do I create a Sitecore Textbox

Tags: c#, authentication, sitecore, sitecore6

I am using SiteCores front end to develop a website.  I was asked to create a log in screen for our intranet.

I am unable to create a TextBox to collect user name/password information as well as a button.

Can these controls be added in the Sitecore Front End, or will I need Visual Studio and Sitecore rocks to develop this.

Do you have any examples?

Thank you!  I appreciate the help/ideas!

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of adding textboxes and making login form using them from **Sitecore** front end. You definitely need to do some coding in Visual Studio (using **Sitecore Rocks** is not necessary).

**Sitecore** login form is like any other asp.net login form. Just remember to run `loggingin` pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in Security API cookbook http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Security%20API%20Cookbook.aspx